# Should I use the "intended" type when using type hinting for function result?

Tags: python, type-hinting

My simple question is how to specify (type hint) the resulting value of a function if the result can take more than one type.

The official PEP 484 documentation states to use the "expected" type (e.g. "This states that the expected type of the name argument is str. Analogically, the expected return type is str.)

Let's say for whatever reason this function can not only return str but also return int or None or any type. The point is that it can take multiple times.

`def get_first_name(last_name: str) -> ???:`

Is the "expected" type the "intended" type? so str?
Or do I have to type hint all possible types?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to say "can also return None"?

Comment: if a function can returns anything, you should think about if you can refactor it to be more decisive and return one or two at most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it says "expected type" it means that type checkers should warn when the actual type doesn't meet the expectation.

`Union` types can be used when a parameter or return value can be multiple types. And the specific case of allowing `None` as a placeholder for a nonexistent value is handled using the `Optional` type. So you would write:

```
def get_first_name(last_name: str) -> Optional[str]:
```